# React App build failure on vercel with Error "react-scripts build" exited with 127

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, vercel, react-scripts

I am newbie on React and I am trying to deploy my React Application build using CRA on vercel. Its failing to deploy with error Message "react-scripts build" exited with 127.

I have tried deleting node modules, package.json lock and reinstalling it. Also tried npm install react-scripts. Also tried env variable CI=false in vercel app but nothing is working[Error Log Image[Package.json details[Package.json details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM0nB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5r2y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTByC.png)